# Can't form EJB relationship across EAR projects. Relationship Attribute Exception?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, ejb

I am trying to access entity beans from one EAR project to another EAR project, but I am getting this error.

> Exception Description: [class
>   com.huwag.ao.server.bvg.tarif.ejb.entity.Tarif] uses a non-entity
>   [class com.huwag.server.ejb.entity.Mandant] as target entity in the
>   relationship attribute [field mandant].

It looks like my **Tarif** can't find my **Mandant** entity. Tarif lives in one ear file whereas Mandant lives in another (the core project so to speak).

My Mandant (in the Core project) looks like this :

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "HUW_AO_MANDANT")
public class Mandant implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MANDANT_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }    
}
```

And in my dependant EAR JAR lives this guy :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HUW_AO_TARIF")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
            name = "getAllTarif",
            query = "SELECT t FROM Tarif t") 
        ,
    @NamedQuery(
            name = "getTarifForMandant",
            query = "SELECT t FROM Tarif t where t.mandantId = :mandant")
})
public class Tarif implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    @JoinColumn(name="MANDANT_ID")
    private Mandant mandant;


    public Mandant getMadant() {
        return mandant;
    }

    public void setMadant(Mandant mandant) {
        this.mandant = mandant;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String firstName) {
        this.name = firstName;
    }
}
```

Architectually it looks like this.

[image]

I am trying to form a relationship from one Entity on another Entity that lives in another deployment artifact.

I am using Glassfish 4. I don't have anything in my persistence.xml, because as I understand, Glassfish 4 just finds these classes instead of looking through the persistence.xml.

- Am I using the relationship annotations correctly?
- Do I need to put these entities in the persistence.xml file?
- Do I need to provide Local/Remote interfaces so that one EAR file can see the other?
- Is it at all possible to form this relationship between EJBs across different packaging artifacts?

Comment: thankyou.. i did need to put the entities in my persistence XML. Put it as an answer and then I can +1 you.

Comment: Do you publish the EAR files independently? You will definitely be able to use EJBs from the core EAR, but I think it is mandatory to have Remote EJB interfaces for them.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any `persistence.xml` files in the dependent ear, I doubt glassfish will know what entities it must use there. So I suppose you need to import that dependency using the `<jar-file>` XML element in your `persistence.xml` file. Also you mapped them correctly, although I would go for a int ID instead of a String.